# scrolling is slower when I have images from server

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios6, uiimageview

What I have is tableView. In each cell I am displaying image and name and some details next to it. Images are on server. For images what I was doing is below.

```
UIImageView *imagePathImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:9999999984];
test1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"imagePath"]];
if ([test1 isEqualToString:@"missing"]) {
    imagePathImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image.png"];
} else {
    imagePathImage.image = [[UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mysite.com/sama/myImages/image%@.jpg", [[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"id"] ]]]] retain];
}
```

I am pulling data in the JSON format.

The problem is when I am scrolling down, loading next item is taking time as for images I have provided server path. If I hide image code,  scrolling is much faster. However when I have images loading images is taking time.

My question is, such behavior in iPhone app is OK or I should download the images (locally) first and then display them?

OR

While storing images, should I change the resolution of image by 60x60 as my image icon size is 60x60.

---

### Edit 1

I used Michael Robinson answer. To resize, I used code from below link.

[Resize Image](http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resize your images to be no larger the largest size you use in your app, this will conserve memory and reduce download times.

If this doesn't help or doesn't improve performance sufficiently, investigate lazy-loading images as they are scrolled into view.

**Edit**: as everyone else has said, you should also load them asynchronously on another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try lazy loading of images . you can get a example [here](http://codeshape.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/creating-a-lazy-loading-uiimageview-for-ios/).

Answer (score 0):

I would load them asynchronically.

Have a look at this tutorial. It is easy to understand and and does nearly exactly what you need. 
http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/

Answer (score 0):

**First**, load images asynchronically with [EGOImageView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading/tree/master/EGOImageView) or by using separate into the threads with NSThread.

```
NSThread *thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(requestImageFromServer) object:nil];
[thread start];
```

**Second**, cache images wich already loaded. EGOImageView have this already. With your own logic - save images to filesystem and take them, previously compare with nil (use NSFileManager).